# Peewee - Insert Many - On Conflict - Proper query structure to preserve specified fields on conflict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, orm, peewee

I am confused at the behavior of a [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/index.html) insert_many on_conflict query. While I thought I had designated to preserve 'created_at' column and update the 'updated_at' column on conflict, the opposite is occurring.

Upon reviewing the database, 'created_at' is newer than 'updated_at'. I have reviewed the docs for [on_conflict](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=on_conflict#Insert.on_conflict). Dialect is SQLite. What is wrong with this query?

```
query = (
            CA.insert_many(data)
            .on_conflict(
                conflict_target=[CA.loc_id,],
                preserve=(
                    CA.score,
                    CA.tags,
                    CA.process_at,
                    CA.created_at,
                    CA.deleted_at,
                )
            )
        ).execute()
```

#### Edit

Based on [@coleifer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254346/coleifer) answer (Thank you for the quick response) I misunderstood the meaning of 'preserve' assuming it meant to preserve columns in the database, not the incoming data.

To qualify my original question, the goal is to define the columns to remain unchanged, especially when there may be few columns in the database to remain unchanged and there are many columns. It seems like [EXCLUDED](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html?highlight=conflict#EXCLUDED) might allow this? I wish I had a few more examples.

Comment: @coleifer Marking as answered. Was hoping to not have to explicitly define each column to preserve into the database. If the table is changed then the new columns must be explicitly defined. It would be more efficient to instead define the columns that would not change, and allow all other columns to be updated. I ended up explicitly defining each column to change on a conflict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to `preserve` the `created_at` (this preserves the new value that you are inserting). Preserve means "use the value we would have inserted".

So you only want to `preserve` the fields you wish to be updated:

```
query = (CA.insert_many(data)
     .on_conflict(
          conflict_target=[CA.loc_id,],
          preserve=(
              CA.score,
              CA.tags,
              CA.process_at,
              CA.updated_at,
          )
        )
    ).execute()
```

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of preserve in relation to the existing data.

If you have a large table, and want to define only the fields to keep unchanged in the database, what would be the syntax to accomplish that?